# Java Future API is not running in parallel inside Quartz Application

Tags: java, concurrency, quartz-scheduler, future

I am creating a Quartz Application in order to schedule tasks and have 10 worker Quartz Threads working in parallel. Now what I want to achieve is to have concurrent processing of my jobs inside each worker thread as well.
 So I thought of using Future API present in Java.

```
public class MyJob{
 private ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

 public void execute(JObExecutionContext jec) throws Exception {
  //Getting values from Job data map
  // Creating custom logger instance (has synchronized getInstance method)
  //Some Database queries

  List<Future<String>> lfs = new ArrayList<>();
  Foo foo = new Foo(logger);
  for(Long long : myList) { //List size ~ 2000
     Future<String> fs = es.submit(()->{
     //Setting stuff
      foo.doHugeJob(); //This takes several minutes
      return "some String";
   });
   lfs.add(fs);
  }
  for(future<String> s : lfs){
   s.get();
  }
}
```

}

Now the problem I am facing here is that all the statement foo.doHugeJob() is not running in parallel. Rather than it is being executed in sequence and I am unable to understand why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you are using separate thread if you are using scheduler ? this will be take care number jobs by it self.

Comment: @Simmant right but we have a constraint here to use 10 worker threads only. Currently one thread takes some 8 hours to complete. So using future I want to reduce it to somewhere near 2hrs

Comment: ok.. then you have to validate what all things you have in doHugeJob method, might be object with lock or collection api causing synchronizes behavior.

Comment: @Simmant I am not using any locks/synchronized collections or methods. All this code contains is bunch of rest, soap and database calls.

Comment: Then I guess you have to check implementation for those api calls, might be that will give you some clue. As I can see source of DriverManager there are few method have synchronized call https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/sql/DriverManager.java

Comment: Might be some API/DB method may define synchronized and that my responsible for this behavior.

Comment: @Simmant I did not have any such problem when I created a new thread and put the method call inside it. Does that makes sense?

Comment: @KaustavSarkar just to be clear when you say they are getting sequentially how are you confirming that? Also what happens when the same code is execute outside of job context..For example what happens when you execute this in a test?

Comment: This will be work fine for single thread but that will not make sense as you are using Quartz, but probably you have to check/debug in your code flow for non concurrent execution, I m pretty much sure DB or web API invoke may cause this issue.